# Posting array to mvc controller as extra parameter for datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I'm posting a datatables request back to the server. As extra search parameter I post an array of strings back to the server. The array is made from a multiselect box.

```
  var flocks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $('.multiselect > option:selected').length; i++) {
        flocks[i] = $('.multiselect > option:selected')[i].value;
  }
```

After the post I see that the array is posted, though weird in my opinion (?) the index is not send with....

```
  .....&flocks[]=Flock 2&flocks[]=Flock 3&flocks[]=Flock 5&flocks[]=Flock 6&...
```

In the method I have a string[] flocks field defined but the value stays null after sending the data.

When I change the ajax call to traditional:true it is working, but then my filtercolumns are not working anymore. This is even harder to fix, so I have to leave that out.

Are there any other ways of sending this? I could send it as a string with a seperator, but that would be the easy option ;)

Comment: Can you show your `ajax` calling code?

Comment: it is the ajax code of datatables.net. Have to see if i can figure out how it does that.

Comment: it is prety complex (and way above my head) but this is the source of datatables: cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js

Comment: Show your codes that includes your "flocks" array to ajax call ?

Comment: ajax: {
                        url: 'GetBatchStatistics',
                        data: function (d) {
                            d.flocks = flocks; }
                    },